# How can i use Restful in angularjs.I used ngResource but its not working .The js file nt executing if i used ngResource

Tags: angularjs, restful-authentication, angularjs-resource

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngResource']);
app.factory('UserFactory', function ($resource) {

     return $resource('/com/vsoft/rest/users', {}, {
         query: {
             method: 'GET',
             params: {},
             isArray: false
         }
     });
 });
app.controller('MyCtrl1', ['$scope', 'UserFactory', function ($scope, UserFactory) {
     UserFactory.get({}, function (userFactory) {
         $scope.firstname = userFactory.firstName;
         $scope.lastname = userFactory.lastName;
         });
     });
 }]);
```

i added above app in my html.But the app and angular-resource.js but my app.js is not exeuting.

If i removed ngResource module and $resource alert is coming.But if i used ngResource im nt getting alert.

Please help in this.If any one knows any Good Example to use Restful services with angularjs .Please Kindly send Url or code.

Please help me.

i called{{firstname}}
in my html but its not coming .

Comment: have you included angular-resource.js file? this blog post provide good explanation for consuming REST service in angular http://blog.brunoscopelliti.com/building-a-restful-web-service-with-angularjs-and-php-more-power-with-resource

Comment: if JS is not executing when you add ngResource it's most likely that you haven't added resource JS file: `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.17/angular-resource.min.js`

Answer (score 0):

I use a service for handling RESTful messages

```
app.service('restService', function ($http, $log) {
    'use strict';

    var self = this;
    var BASE_URL = "base/url/";
    //First way how to do it
    self.httpGet = function (url) {
        $log.info("HTTP Get", url);

        return postProcess($http({method: 'GET', url: BASE_URL + url}));
    };

    //Second way how to do it
    self.httpPut = function (url, object) {
        $log.info("HTTP Put", url);
        return postProcess($http.put(BASE_URL + url, object));
    };

    self.httpPost = function (url, object) {
        $log.info("HTTP Post", url);
        return postProcess($http.post(BASE_URL + url, object));
    };

    self.httpDelete = function (url) {
        $log.info("HTTP Delete", url);
        return postProcess($http.delete(BASE_URL + url));
    };

    function postProcess(httpPromise) {
        return httpPromise.then(function (response) {
            if (response.status === 200) {
                return response;
            }
            //Other than 200 is not ok (this is application specific)
            failure(response);
        }, function (response) {
            failure(response);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Promise for failure HTTP codes
     * @param response the HTTP response
     */
    function failure(response) {
        //Error handling
    }
});
```

usable as

```
    restService.httpGet("categories").then(function (response) {
        categoryData = angular.fromJson(response.data);
        //Broadcast an event to tell that the data is ready to be used
        $rootScope.$broadcast("categoriesReady");
    });
```